# Encapsulating a control inside an exception

Tags: c#, .net

Relatively new to C#/.NET/GUI programming, but here goes.  Right now I'm writing a business application at work using WinForms.  I have about 5 textboxes and 1 combobox that I want to verify if is empty and if so then tell the user and set focus on that control.  How should I go about doing this?

I could either have an if statement that checks each control:

```
if (usernameField IsNullOrEmpty) then:
  setFocus(UsernameField);
  return;

if (addressField IsNullOrEmpty) then:
  setFocus(addressField);
  return;

continue with rest of application as normal...
```

Or I could do this with exceptions:

```
try {
  if (usernameField IsNullOrEmpty) then:
    throw new Exception(usernameField);

  if (addressField IsNullOrEmpty) then:
    throw new Exception(addressField);

} catch (Exception e) {
  setFocus(ControlField) // encapsulate in exception some way?
}
```

Or to prevent code duplication, just write a function:

```
try {
  checkField(usernameField);

  checkField(addressField);

} catch (Exception e) {
  setFocus(ControlField) // encapsulate in exception some way?
} 

void checkField(control ctrl) {
  if (ctrl IsEmptyOrNull)
    throw new Exception(ctrl);
}
```

Being relatively new to GUI programming, does a text field being empty deserve an exception or would this be considered normal program flow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Throwing Exceptions for program flow is not recommended.

Write a helper method.

```
private bool IsTextboxValid(Textbox ctrl)
{
  if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(ctrl.Text))
  {  
    ctrl.Focus();
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

And to use it:

```
if(!IsTextboxValid(addressBox)) return;
if(!IsTextboxValid(nameBox)) return;
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.  So would something like this not deserve exception-handling?

Comment: The helper method does not need an exception handler because it's verifying the value of a known control.  If you suspect that ctrl is null sometimes, you can add a check for that and do something else, but personally, I would leave the null ref exception or throw an ArgumentNullException instead.

Answer (score 2):

I would **not** use an exception, exceptions should be thrown in exceptional situations, user not filling in a field doesn't count.  As for actually detecting the empty control and setting focus, there are tons of ways, like simple if checks as you have, to more complicated solutions with binding and validation and all that.

Comment: Always looking to learn new things so I will check out binding and validation.

Comment: There are things like WPF, but everything has it's price in complexity and learning curve.  Depends on how complicated your application is, it may make more sense to keep things simple vanilla (though slightly ugly) win forms code.